# Access QGIS environment with Conda

Tags: python, conda, qgis

Hi I wonder if one can access the QGIS python environment on windows from the CMD or Anaconda Prompt, instead of opening OSGeo4W Shell and typing 'py3_env'? 
I tried to use the 'cd' function to the QGIS directory, and then typing 'conda install -c r rpy2' but it still dosent get the same results.

My goal here is to install some python modules with conda (rpy2) that should work in QGIS3.

I hope that somebody can help me.